# Grub takes 45 Secs to show boot menu

Tags: grub2

since some time I have a problem with grub.
After the post screen at computer startup I get a black screen for about 45 seconds till the boot menu shows up.
After selecting the system to boot everything is blazingly fast as it should. Only the boot menu itself takes a eternity to show up.

I removed all hard disks except the system disk, installed Ubuntu 16.04 (as a test) and now even changed the mainboard and CPU (due to another problem)

Nothing has helped. Grub used to come up in seconds before.

Is there anything I can do to isolate that problem?

My system is Kubuntu 14.04 on a i3-6100 CPU, 16 GB RAM and 250GB ssd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

update grub has thrown several thousands of nonsense entries in the grub.cfg (the file was ~16.000 lines big!)

After deleting the memtest86+ file and an old linux image from /boot and running upate-grub again everything was fine.

Though I don't understand what was going on there the error is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your BIOS settings. Your "Boot Order", which specifies the order in which the BIOS tries to boot from. The 1st device in your list doesn't respond, (and maybe devices 2 through N-1). This takes about 45 seconds. Then the BIOS tries device N (the right one) and boots. `grub` ensues.

There's a key <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> YMMV that you can hit during early boot (before the black screen) to access your Boot Order. Adjust it.

Comment: Definitely not.
As I mentioned in my post I removed ALL other drives for testing.

Comment: Physically removing a drive does NOT keep the BIOS from trying to boot from it, and timing out. Adjusting the boot order, or connecting your drive to a lower numbered controller.

Comment: Doesn't the controller see that there's no drive attached?
However, meanwhile I changed the mainboard, connecting the disk to Sata1 and checked the boot order in BIOS. No change at all.

What I found out is: If I wait for the screen to flicker (still staying black, though) and the hit enter the PC starts at the moment the boot menu appears at the screen. So obviously grub is already loaded at this time. If I hit enter before grub is loaded the key stroke is ignored